# Grouping in sql server 2008

Tags: sql-server-2008, group-by

I have used below query to group the data.But grouping is not done in that.

select Max(wo) as WO,sum(Trx_Qty) as Qty  from #temptbale
group by WO,Trx_Qty

```
  WO       Qty
WO-1010    3
WO-1012    3
WO-1010    5
WO-1013    7
WO-1015    8
WO-1016    10
WO-1009    12
```

desired result :

```
 WO        QTY
WO-1010   8
WO-1012   3
WO-1013   7
WO-1015   8
WO-1016   10
WO-1009   12
```

Comment: Why are you grouping by `Trx_Qty` and taking the `MAX()` of `WO`?

Answer (score 0):

Remove Trx_Qty from the group by clause.

```
select WO, 
       sum(Trx_Qty) as Qty 
from #temptbale
group by WO
```

Comment: Thanks Mikael Eriksson !!